# Load static JSON at runtime in webpack build

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, assets

I have built a tiny webapp with vue-cli. Now I have a JSON configuration file that has to be loaded at runtime, because the JSON will be regularly replaced on the production server.

I think I'm on the right track with:

```js
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.json$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    exclude: '/node_modules',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]'
                    }
                }
            ],
        },
    },
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? './' : '/',
}
```

But I get this error when I run `npm run build`:
`Module parse failed: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'export default __web...'`

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Where you able to solve this?

Comment: Not sure, I don't remember the context, sorry.